# padding right with "&HBB" VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing the vb.net to right padding the values. my code as follows:

```
 Dim Ni As Byte() = { &HA6, &H02, &H01,....}    
 Dim Nca As Byte()  = { &H12, &H00, &H02,....}    
 If (Ni.Length <= Nca.Length - 36) Then

        Dim padLength As Integer  = Nca.Length - 36 - Ni.Length
        Dim padvalue As Byte() = {&HBB}
        For Each w As Integer In padLength
            Console.Write(Ni =Ni+ Ni.rigtPadding({&HBB}))
        Next

 End If
```

my code is not working. If Ni.Length<=Nca.Length-36, I need consist of the full Ni padded to the right with Nca-36-Ni bytes of hex value "&HBB". it is might be more than 1 "&HBB" need to be padded on the right side. and then I need the final result of Ni with the padding.

Ni is Issuer public key, Nca is CA public key ,the final result I want should be {&H6A, 02, 11, FF,....., BB,BB,BB}

Thank you very much for any help and comment.

Comment: Trying using string X format specifier.  After padding in string convert back

Comment: Hi @Ramankingdom thank you, I search X format, but still confused.

Comment: This is not a valid loop: `For Each w As Integer In padLength`, it shouldn't even compile (I hope it doesn't, otherwise your compiler is seriously messed up!). That loop is currently trying to iterate every Integer in an... Integer??

Comment: In order to iterate from one number to another use a regular [**`For` loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement). I suggest you read up on how [**`For Each` loops**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) work as well.

Comment: @VisualVincent, thank you, as I asked, I know the problem with my code, but I don't know how to write this in the right way. I need rightPadding Ni with &HBB, if it is not enough length.

Comment: No one besides you knows what `Ni` is. We can't help if you don't give us all information about your code. But if `Ni.rightPadding()` is a valid method then fixing the loop should _perhaps_ fix your problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent   Ni is Issuer public key, and the format is {&H6A, 02, 11, FF,.....}

Comment: @VisualVincent,I need to add the &HBB if Ni is shorter than CA public key length-36, the final result I want should be {&H6A, 02, 11, FF,....., BB,BB,BB}

Comment: Please update your question with the `Ni` declaration and all other relevant code necessary for us to be able to reproduce it on our own (but as small as possible!). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Using dummy/placeholder code is fine, as long as we can use it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent, Hi I updated my question, I hope it would be help. I can't post all the code, because it's a lot. I think the value of the Ni or Nca are not important, because I  use a function to pass these two values and compare their length. I only need a method to padding the Ni if it not long enough.

Comment: Again, all code isn't needed, just enough to reproduce your issue. Using dummy code (like you did with your arrays by giving them a pre-defined value) is often much more effective and easier for us to read and understand. I posted an answer by the way, what you added was all info I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using regular arrays this is relatively simple (but could be even simpler using a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)).

First you need to call [**`Array.Resize()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to increase the size of the array. Then you can use a regular [**`For` loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) to fill the new space.

```
Dim prevLength As Integer = Ni.Length 'Store the previous length so we can start looping from it.
Array.Resize(Ni, Ni.Length + padLength) 'Take the original length and increase it by how much needs to be padded.

'Iterate from the beginning of the padding to the new end of the array.
For i = prevLength To Ni.Length - 1
    Ni(i) = &HBB
Next
```

I also suggest you read up a little on how arrays work: [**Arrays in Visual Basic - Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/).

Comment: Thanks for your response and patient, your code didn't give any error, but I test the result of Ni, there is nothing changed.

Comment: @ccy : If you place a breakpoint on the `Ni(i) = &HBB` line, is it ever hit? Is your `If` ever even entered?

Comment: I made the Ni. Length =193  and Nca.Length =240, and it should padded 11 &HBB

Comment: @ccy : Try stepping through your code and inspecting the variables using breakpoints. Send me a screenshot with a breakpoint at the `Dim padLength As Integer = ...` line and expand the two arrays in the Autos/Locals window so I can see their contents (the window(s) can be un-docked from their positions by dragging them).

Comment: I debug it, I think the Resize function is not working, because in my code, Ni= _certificateSignRequest.GetIssuerPublicKey.

Comment: _certificateSignRequest.GetIssuerPublicKey this function is getting the Publickey from a file, I test your code, after the Risize, _certificateSignRequest.GetIssuerPublicKey.Length didn't change.

Comment: I declare a new variable named Ni, and signed _certificateSignRequest.GetIssuerPublicKey to Ni. Your code is working, thank you very much.

Comment: @ccy : Glad I could help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually resize NCI using `Redim Preserve` and set the padding character:

```
Dim Padding as Byte = &HBB
Dim Nca As Byte()  = { &H12, &H00, &H02,....}
Dim Ni As Byte() = { &HA6, &H02, &H01,....} 
Dim len = Nca.Length - 36 
if (len > Ni.Length) Then
    Redim Preserve Ni(len+1)
    For i As Integer = len to Ni.Length-1
        Ni(i) = Padding
    Next
End if
```

Or you can use LINQ:

```
 Dim Padding as Byte = &HBB
 Dim Pad =Function(i) If(i < Nca.Length, Nca(i), padding)
 Dim Nca As Byte()  = { &H12, &H00, &H02,....} 
 Dim len as integer = Nca.Length - 36  
 if len > Ni.Length Then Ni = Enumerable.Range(0, len+1).Select(Pad).ToArray()
```